# Fetching data from multiple tables in laravel5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables **posts** and **sharedposts**. sharedposts table has columns "user_id", "updated_at" and "post_id" where as **posts** table has 'id', 'title' and 'body'. I know about the relations to link both tables. All i want to do is to display each post ordered by 'updated_at' from both the tables. Please help with both query builder and eloquent way. Thanku

Answer (score 0):

The code is not tested, but you can try this:

```
Post::whereHas('sharedpost',function($query){
    $query->orderBy('updated_at');
})->get()
```

Comment: what are u trying to do basically?

Comment: Sort all post according to updated_at column in sharedpost table.

Comment: alright now let consider i have another table **posts** i have to consider those posts also and then compare to these **shared posts** and whichever is latest from both of these that particular post should be displayed first

Comment: If this answer solved your problem accept this answer and create a new question for new problem. And, to join table you can use `merge()` function. see [https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-merge)

Comment: it is not solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit different approach if there won't be to much of the updates of the models? This way I suppose the read should be faster (somebody please correct me if I'm wrong here)

Add another field to the table by creating new migration and [adding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns)

```
$table->timestamp('last_updated');
```

Then  using [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events) update the field whenever the `Post` or `SharedPost` is updated by adding this to `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    Post::saving(function ($post) {
        $post->last_updated = Carbon::now();
    });
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work though and it would be appreciated if you returned a feedback as I'm lazy to try it out myself at the moment :). Worse case scenario you might need to change the method as:

```
public function boot()
{
    SharedPost::saved(function ($sharedpost) {
        $sharedpost->post->last_updated = Carbon::now();
        $sharedpost->save();
    });
}
```

or you could check out Observers if you don't want the code in the `AppServiceProvider`. Haven't used it but it seems straightforward.

Then you could simply `Post::orderBy('last_updated')->get();`

This way you will have one or two more inputs to your database but I think (and guys please correct me if I'm wrong) the `get()` should be faster. Keep in mind I'm far from a MySQL expert.

And in the end, you can make it even faster by saving this data to Cache using Redis.